# html5 drop change the drop item's class

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that I am dragging over and dropping inside another div. However, I want the dropped item to change its class when its dropped. I am using vanilla js for this, so no jquery answers please.

```
function dragThis(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData("Div", e.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("Div");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

So in the function drop i am looking for a way to change the dropped elements class.

Comment: Where is your code in the drop method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the element (`el`), which you get by `document.getElementById()`, you can manipulate its class as follows:

To remove a class:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.remove(className);
else
  el.className = el.className.replace(new RegExp('(^|\\b)' + className.split(' ').join('|') + '(\\b|$)', 'gi'), ' ');
```

To add a class:

```
if (el.classList)
  el.classList.add(className);
else
  el.className += ' ' + className;
```

Code taken from here: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: This worked, thank you. I used:
    document.getElementById(data).classList.remove('col-sm-2','drag-example');
    document.getElementById(data).classList.add('col-sm-12','changed');